# Escape single curly brace in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am looking to generate a string like `\usepackage{mypackage}` from a Django template.

Suppose there is a variable `package.name` in the context how can I generate this?

Firstly I tried, `\usepackage{{{package.name}}}` but that throws `TemplateSyntaxError`
Then I tried `\usepackage{ {{package.name}} }` which works but has the two spaces in the output, ie, `\usepackage{ mypackage }`

Is there an easy way to generate this string with Django template engine?

Comment: Let's assume your package name is "PackageA", do you want to make it look like `usepackage{PackageA}` this on the client-side?

Comment: Yes exactly, just a plain string inside curly braces. But i'm not using it in HTML

Comment: Can you put up your code and where you are using it, so that we can understand your problem better, thank you

Comment: @KhanAsfiReza It's [LaTeX syntax](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX). OP is probably rendering dynamic documents, but sometimes you have to include additional packages for some specific feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also print strings with the mustache-syntax e.g.: `{{ 'random string' }}`. So we can print the corresponding curly brace like this:

```
\usepackage{{ '{' }}{{ package.name }}{{ '}' }}
```

Output:

```
\usepackage{mypackage}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this using `span`

```html
\usepackage{<span>{{package.name}}</span>}
```

Answer (score 0):

one option is that you can write a template tag that will render it as you want and give the package name as a variable